# How do you use the Convert function with RowFilter/CustomFilter when column name has special characters?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, rowfilter

I want to convert all my column fields to string for easy filtering, but one of my columns is named **item#**.  How can I use Convert() in this way or is there a better solution?

```
dv.CustomFilter = string.Format("Convert('{0}', 'System.String') LIKE '%{1}%'", columnname, text)
```

I tried the following syntaxes with the '[]' brackets, but neither are working.

```
dv.CustomFilter = string.Format("Convert('[{0}]', 'System.String') LIKE '%{1}%'", columnname, text)

dv.CustomFilter = string.Format("[Convert('{0}', 'System.String')] LIKE '%{1}%'", columnname, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right... i'd suggest following. [] is to escape # character that you've talked about. Also, I'm putting % before and after "text" so that it searches for any column name with that.

dv.CustomFilter = string.format("CONVERT(["+columnname+"], System.String) LIKE '%"+text+"%'");

Comment: I guess my question wasn't as clear as I thought.  I'm trying to apply a filter to a dataview through the CustomFilter property.  The filter string will come from a text field.  The reason I'm using Convert() is because the 'LIKE' operator doesn't work with comparing a different type with strings.  The challenge I'm facing is that the column name has a special character in it.  I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: The column name already has a '#' in it.  I would have to strip that out before I can use ["+columname+"], wouldn't I?